# What are these warning that fleetctl is outputting?

Tags: vagrant, coreos, fleetctl

Running the command `fleetctl load registry@1.service registry-presence@1.service` I get the following output:

```
2015/05/08 10:25:26 WARN fleetctl.go:772: Error retrieving Unit(registry@1.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/registry%401.service?alt=json: forwarding request denied
2015/05/08 10:30:31 WARN fleetctl.go:772: Error retrieving Unit(registry-presence@1.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/registry-presence%401.service?alt=json: forwarding request denied
2015/05/08 10:36:14 WARN fleetctl.go:772: Error retrieving Unit(registry@1.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/registry%401.service?alt=json: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed)
2015/05/08 10:42:44 WARN fleetctl.go:772: Error retrieving Unit(registry-presence@1.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/registry-presence%401.service?alt=json: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed)
2015/05/08 10:54:46 WARN fleetctl.go:772: Error retrieving Unit(registry@1.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/registry%401.service?alt=json: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed)
2015/05/08 10:57:51 WARN fleetctl.go:772: Error retrieving Unit(registry-presence@1.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/registry-presence%401.service?alt=json: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed)
2015/05/08 10:58:12 WARN fleetctl.go:772: Error retrieving Unit(registry@1.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/registry%401.service?alt=json: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed)
2015/05/08 11:02:43 WARN fleetctl.go:772: Error retrieving Unit(registry-presence@1.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/registry-presence%401.service?alt=json: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed)
```

This just repeats, I've left the command running for over 30 minutes. When I press CTRL-C and run `fleetctl list-unit-files` I see the following:

```
UNIT                            HASH    DSTATE          STATE           TARGET
registry-presence@1.service     f54aa0d loaded          inactive        0d8d13be.../172.17.8.101
registry@1.service              d233714 loaded          inactive        0d8d13be.../172.17.8.101
```

And the output of `fleetctl list-units` is:

```
UNIT                            MACHINE                         ACTIVE          SUB
```

If I run the load command with `-block-attempts=2` it gives the same errors but completes and the output of `fleetctl list-unit-files` is:

```
UNIT                            HASH    DSTATE          STATE           TARGET
registry-presence@1.service     f54aa0d loaded          loaded        0d8d13be.../172.17.8.101
registry@1.service              d233714 loaded          loaded        0d8d13be.../172.17.8.101
```

And the output of `fleetctl list-units` is:

```
UNIT                            MACHINE                         ACTIVE          SUB
registry-presence@1.service     0d8d13be.../172.17.8.101        inactive        dead
registry@1.service              0d8d13be.../172.17.8.101        inactive        dead
```

I'm wondering what the WARN logs trying to tell me, what registry is it talking about?

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me also when running fleetctl from my local machine to a distant cluster.

The registry it's talking about is the fleet registry, the units that have been submitted and/or loaded in with `fleetctl submit` or `fleetctl load`.

What I usually do in those cases is connecting to one of the nodes, and run my `fleetctl start` command from there. Then you can run them from your local machine without any more problems.

What I suspect is that for some reason the unit file is not loaded in the whole cluster when you run that command.